# Use Chartboost with Admob Mediation (rewarded video)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I follow these steps to use chartboost with admob mediation:

1. Add the Google Mobile Ads SDK
2. Add `ChartboostAdapter.framework` into my Xcode project
3. Add  `Chartboost.framework` into my Xcode project
4. Add my app and publishing campaign on Chartboost.
5. Set payment details on Chartboost for activating the campaign.
6. Enable the Chartboost network in AdMob.
7. Set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES under
   Build Settings in Xcode.

In AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import Firebase

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()
        GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "pub-*******")
}
```

In GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import AdSupport

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self 

        if(!GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady) {
            requestRewardedVideo()
        }
    }

    func requestRewardedVideo () {
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(request, withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-**********")
    }

    @IBAction func showVideo(_ sender: Any) {
        if(GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady){
            GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)

        } else {
            print("NOT READY!")
        }
    }


    //GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate methods

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen")
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose")
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-6156127992132548/2632148110")
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive")
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying")
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAdWillLeaveApplication(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        print("rewardBasedVideoAdWillLeaveApplication")
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
        print("Should reward user with \(reward.amount) \(reward.type)")
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
        print("didFailToLoadWithError")
    }

}
```

When i run this, it shows me an ad sometimes. But the problems is it always gives a warning:

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 "No ad returned from any ad
>   server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No ad returned from any ad
>   server., NSLocalizedFailureReason=No ad returned from any ad server.}

Am I doing right or is there any other step?

Comment: Why -1 for this question? I think, I gave a brief explanation about my problem and also this is not duplicated.